# How to sort values in pandas based on a column that has repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

```
           name_1  name_2   Temp      x1   x2  
0           a        b     293.35     0.0  1.0  
0           a        b     293.35     0.5  0.5  
0           a        b     293.35     1.0  0.0  
0           a        b     295.35     0.0  1.0  
0           a        b     295.35     0.5  0.5  
0           a        b     295.35     1.0  0.0  
0           a        b     297.35     0.0  1.0  
0           a        b     297.35     0.5  0.5  
0           a        b     297.35     1.0  0.0 
1           c        d     294.35     0.0  1.0  
1           c        d     294.35     0.5  0.5  
1           c        d     294.35     1.0  0.0  
1           c        d     296.35     0.0  1.0  
1           c        d     296.35     0.5  0.5  
1           c        d     296.35     1.0  0.0  
1           c        d     299.35     0.0  1.0  
1           c        d     299.35     0.5  0.5  
1           c        d     299.35     1.0  0.0
2           a        c     300.35     0.0  1.0  
2           a        c     305.35     0.5  0.5  
2           a        c     310.35     1.0  0.0
```

I would like to arrange the data such that the Temp are repeating based on x1 and x2 to get this:

```
           name_1 name_2   Temp       x1   x2  
0           a        b     293.35    0.0  1.0 
0           a        b     295.35    0.0  1.0  
0           a        b     297.35    0.0  1.0  
0           a        b     293.35    0.5  0.5  
0           a        b     295.35    0.5  0.5  
0           a        b     297.35    0.5  0.5 
0           a        b     293.35    1.0  0.0  
0           a        b     295.35    1.0  0.0  
0           a        b     297.35    1.0  0.0
1           c        d     294.35    0.0  1.0  
1           c        d     296.35    0.0  1.0  
1           c        d     299.35    0.0  1.0  
1           c        d     294.35    0.5  0.5  
1           c        d     296.35    0.5  0.5  
1           c        d     299.35    0.5  0.5  
1           c        d     294.35    1.0  0.0  
1           c        d     296.35    1.0  0.0  
1           c        d     299.35    1.0  0.0
2           a        c     300.35    0.0  1.0  
2           a        c     305.35    0.5  0.5  
2           a        c     310.35    1.0  0.0
```

I got close using the following:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Temp')['Temp'].cumcount()
df.sort_values(by=['new', 'Temp', "name_1", "name_2"])
```

This code yields:

```
           name_1 name_2    Temp       x1   x2  
0           a        b     293.35     0.0  1.0 
1           c        d     294.35     0.0  1.0  
0           a        b     295.35     0.0  1.0  
2           a        c     300.35     0.0  1.0
```

The issue with this is that TRange is not being repeated based on name_1 and name_2 like the desired output.

Comment: You don't need `groupby` at all.  Just use `sort_values`.

Comment: `df.sort_values(by='x1')`?

Comment: It doesn't work alone.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How does this not work?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It gives the output you pasted as expected.

Comment: If you just put sort values it won't change the structure of your data inplace. You should do: df = df.sort_values('x1') or df.sort_values('x1', inplace=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by `x1` values then  by index using `kind='mergesort'` to ensure your values stay sorted:

```
>>> df.sort_values('x1', kind='mergesort').sort_index(kind='mergesort')

  name_1 name_2    Temp   x1   x2
0      a      b  293.35  0.0  1.0
0      a      b  295.35  0.0  1.0
0      a      b  297.35  0.0  1.0
0      a      b  293.35  0.5  0.5
0      a      b  295.35  0.5  0.5
0      a      b  297.35  0.5  0.5
0      a      b  293.35  1.0  0.0
0      a      b  295.35  1.0  0.0
0      a      b  297.35  1.0  0.0
1      c      d  294.35  0.0  1.0
1      c      d  296.35  0.0  1.0
1      c      d  299.35  0.0  1.0
1      c      d  294.35  0.5  0.5
1      c      d  296.35  0.5  0.5
1      c      d  299.35  0.5  0.5
1      c      d  294.35  1.0  0.0
1      c      d  296.35  1.0  0.0
1      c      d  299.35  1.0  0.0
2      a      c  300.35  0.0  1.0
2      a      c  305.35  0.5  0.5
2      a      c  310.35  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort on x1. You can specify a stable sorting algorithm:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='x1', kind='mergesort')
```

grouping and applying a cumcount is going nothing other than keeping the original order of the other parameters, which a stable sorting algorithm is already doing.

cf. [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) documentation for reference.

Comment: This is close but the issue is that other name_1 (i.e.=c) and name_2 (i.e. =d) also have x1 that are 0.0, so it ends up splitting the data such that once all x1 = 0 is done, it begins x1 = 0.5 for the name_1 =a and name_2 = b

Comment: @mozway. The idea of `kind='mergesort'` is clearly yours. +1